# Windows/Cygwin - Can't use pybind11 - make error

Tags: c++, python-3.x, windows, cygwin, pybind11

I want to integrate in a project the practical tool pybind11.
My work environment is windows.

To install pybind11, there is this page: [Pybind First setps](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html)

I tried several times under windows and several days (3),
with Eclipse, then with Python and Mingw.
then with Visual Studio

**After all this I tried with Linux and in 1 hour I came to this example:**

```
#include <pybind11 / pybind11.h>

int add (int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE (example, m) {
    m.doc () = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring
    m.def ("add", & add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

> c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std = c ++ 11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`

With the test in addition to Python.

**After this, I decided to make it succeed with cygwin**.

Here is where I am:

```
easy_install-3.6 pip
python3 -m pip install pytest
python3 -m pip install pybind11
python3 -m pip install python-config
```

Then under pybind11-master

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make check -j 4
```

I have two warning and a note:

> warning: "pybind11 :: buffer :: buffer (pybind11 :: handle, bool)" is deprecated: Use reinterpret_borrow  () or reinterpret_steal  () [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

When linking, here is an error but there are plenty.

> /tmp/ccqNl6ln.ltrans0.ltrans.o::(.text+0x12f16): undefined reference to "pybind11 :: index_error :: index_error () [clone .lto_priv.4841] [clone .lto_priv.4883]"

pybind11 would really be a **plus** for the project.
But I can not use it on Windows.

**Has anyone ever compiled pybind11 with cygwin?**

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after installing with pip the 3 modules

```
python3 -m pip install pytest
python3 -m pip install pybind11
python3 -m pip install python-config
```

the following example, works

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add (int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE (example, m) {
    m.doc () = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring
    m.def ("add", & add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

if compiled as:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix) -lpython3.6m
```

Comment: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory

Comment: have you installed the library ?