# How to use pybind11 in omnet++ projects like veins

Tags: omnet++, pybind11, veins

please suggest how to use pybind11 in omnet++ projects like veins. I am getting compile time errors. I can see so many posibilities with python being used in omnet++ simulation tool.

I tried this link [Windows/Cygwin - Can't use pybind11 - make error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115907/windows-cygwin-cant-use-pybind11-make-error) for setting flags but not was successful.

I am using Instant veins vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added

1. Include directories **/usr/include/pybind11, /usr/include/python2.7** in paths and symbols
2. In Omnet++ Makemake options --> link added **python2.7**

It works...

Thanks SO.